# Set the SelectionChanged event of a ComboBox while binding its SelectedItem and ItemsSource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to set up a ComboBox with its options binded from a list of strings, its default selected value binded from a setting, and with an event handler for its selection changed.

I want to configure it all using XAML like so:

```
    <ComboBox Name="RoutesComboBox"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultRoute}" 
              SelectionChanged="RouteFilter_SelectionChanged" />
```

But when I do that on startup it throws the error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll

If I only do some of it in XAML, then either set the `SelectionChanged` event or the `ItemsSource` programatically in C# like below it works fine. But I have a lot of these ComboBoxes so I would rather do it straight in the XAML.

```
<ComboBox Name="RoutesComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultRoute}" />
```

With this C#:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Routes
{
    get { return LubricationDatabase.GetRoutes(); }
}

public string DefaultRoute
{
    get { return MySettings.Default.DefaultRoute; }
    set { } /* side question: without this, it throws a parse exception. Any idea why? */
}

public MainWindow()
{
     this.DataContext = this;
     InitializeComponent();

     RoutesComboBox.SelectionChanged += RouteFilter_SelectionChanged;
 }
```

I've also tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666485/2374028):

```
private string _defaultRoute;
public string DefaultRoute
{
    get { return MySettings.Default.DefaultRoute; }
    set
    {
        if (_defaultRoute != value)
        {
            _defaultRoute = value;

            // this fires before `SelectedValue` has been 
            // updated, and the handler function uses that,
            // so I manually set it here.
            RoutesComboBox.SelectedValue = value;
            SelectionChangedHandler(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Which is okay, but is pretty bulky and probably more work than is worth it when I can just programatically assign the `SelectionChanged` event.

Again if possible I'd like to do it all using XAML because I have a lot of these ComboBoxes and initializing them all like this in the C# will look awful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you binding with `SelectedItem` when you're not going to update the item when a user changes their selection?  Not sure what your event handler is doing, but I have a working solution just the way you wanted it.

In short, you need to keep track of the `DefaultRoute` using a backing field.  Also, you need to notify the UI when the selected item changes in your view model; which by the way is something you don't seem to be doing, MVVM.  You should only be hooking into the selection changed event if you plan on updating the view in some way.  All other changes should be handled in your view models `DefaultRoute` setter

### XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="RoutesComboBox"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultRoute}" 
      SelectionChanged="RouteFilter_SelectionChanged" />
```

### Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Routes
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        }
    }

    public string DefaultRoute
    {
        get
        {
            return _defaultRoute;
        }
        set
        {
            _defaultRoute = value;
            // Handle saving/storing setting here, when selection has changed
            //MySettings.Default.DefaultRoute = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        DefaultRoute = MySettings.Default.DefaultRoute;
    }

    private string _defaultRoute;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void RouteFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public static class MySettings
{
    public static class Default
    {
        public static string DefaultRoute = "a";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! You nailed it, thank you. To answer your question, I didn't want the user just changing what route they last selected to changed their default route. This also took care of another thing I was manually doing which was keeping the selected item of different comboboxes with the same items synchronized. I'm new to MVVM and binding, as you can see. Thanks again.